# Are the stories from Chashukei Chemed real?

Tags: jewish-books, agada-stories-legends

Is there any information about the anonymous stories from the series of seforim Chashukei Chemed from R' Yitzchok Silberstein if they are real or just made up?

One that was particularly bugging me emotionally is a [case about a person who](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49708&st=&pgnum=441&hilite=) tricked someone to bring a sefer Torah through a 12-hour-long flight.

Comment: Do you know if there’s an English version of this book online anywhere

Comment: His English books are called *What If...* - possibly indicating they're hypotheticals.

Comment: Either he made them up to explain a halachic concept, or a bored teenager made them up (and then asked him) just to get an interesting response.

Comment: I think it says in the description of the book that it's fiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rav Osher Weiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osher_Weiss) has stated in [public](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDxoHmIZkS0) that many of the cases are theoretical and never happened. I personally think that is obvious based on the nature of the questions he deals with.

Comment: What's the timestamp?

Comment: It's in the first minute, around 50 seconds in.